# How do I require user to uninstall previous version with NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I have just started using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).
It works very well but I find the documentation a bit unstructured.
How do I require user to uninstall previous version before installing a new version with [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)?

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is an open source system to create Windows installers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NSIS is a great Windows Installer.  Here is how I use NSIS to uninstall the current version while installing a new version of the same application.  Add the following function to your NSIS script.

```
Function .onInit

         Exec $INSTDIR\uninst.exe 

FunctionEnd
```

Also you can check out [this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new) link on the NSIS wiki on "Auto-uninstall old before installing new".

Comment: Don't use $INSTDIR. Use the value you read from the registry to make sure it's the right one.

Comment: Wont this start the uninstall in the background, and allow the user to continue with the installation *while the uninstall is happening*?

Answer (score 18):

Another approach is to make a `UninstallPrevious` hidden section and make it run before all other sections in the installer.  I also suggest making the uninstaller run silently.

```
; The "" makes the section hidden.
Section "" SecUninstallPrevious

    Call UninstallPrevious

SectionEnd

Function UninstallPrevious

    ; Check for uninstaller.
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "${HKLM_REG_KEY}" "InstallDir"

    ${If} $R0 == ""        
        Goto Done
    ${EndIf}

    DetailPrint "Removing previous installation."    

    ; Run the uninstaller silently.
    ExecWait '"$R0\Uninstall.exe /S"'

    Done:

FunctionEnd
```

The advantage of this approach is that the user won't uninstall the old version until they're ready to install the new version.  Furthermore, they don't even have to make a decision about uninstalling the old version, it just magically disappears.

Of course, depending on your needs, you may want the user to confirm uninstalling, in which case use the spinner_den's approach.

Comment: When you get data into `$R0` shouldn't you use it in the `ExecWait` ?

Answer (score 2):

I reuse the `UninstallString` or `QuietUninstallString` registry keys that get written during the install to later determine the uninstaller command.

A couple defines at the top:

```
!define PROJECT_REG_UNINSTALL_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PROJECT_NAME}"
!define PROJECT_UNINSTALL_EXE "uninstall.exe"
```

In the installer `Section`:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PROJECT_REG_UNINSTALL_KEY}" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\${PROJECT_UNINSTALL_EXE}" _?=$INSTDIR'
WriteRegStr HKLM "${PROJECT_REG_UNINSTALL_KEY}" "QuietUninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\${PROJECT_UNINSTALL_EXE}" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
```

And then in your `.onInit` grab the registry key value (would exist if your app was already installed this way) and run it:

```
${If} ${Silent}
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "${PROJECT_REG_UNINSTALL_KEY}" "QuietUninstallString"
${Else}
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "${PROJECT_REG_UNINSTALL_KEY}" "UninstallString"
${EndIf}
ExecWait "$R0"
```