# Why my uninstaller is not working properly in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I have written a nsis script in which i need to prompt the user where there was previous installation and uninstall the previous version if user select the same folder as previous version.It is working fine.But suppose user choose different directory than the uninstall.exe is giving problem.

```
Ex-suppose user install version 1.2 in folder a and then agian version 1.2 in folder B .
Than in every case the uninstall .exe is pointing to folderb not folder a.How can i solve this issue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the uninstaller, `$instdir` is just the directory the uninstaller is in so the uninstaller itself should not care.

You say you are prompting the user, so you already know the location of the old install so all you have to do is to [invoke the uninstaller with the special parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4677432/3501) so it knows where to uninstall from...